# Dividing form into two columns with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the correct way to style `form` with [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) in the following scenario:

[image: two columns form view]

1. I need to use fieldset (that will be styled later)
2. I need to divide `form` into two columns
3. Each column has label+control, some will have label+control1+control2 etc.

I am new to bootstrap. I have come to the following [solution (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9HkUb/2/).

The question is: **is this the correct way to do this?** Does it not violate the bootstrap semantics?

**I do not understand when to use `form-group`**, am I using it correctly?

Should I not include **some `class="row"` here for correct semantics**?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
... <some content here> ....

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Portfolio</legend>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label1</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label2</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label3</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label1</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label2</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

I have seen all Bootstrap form examples, but I do not get how to separate `form` into two columns. I have also read the whole [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/), but I feel that this is not the right way how to use `col` and other classes.

Answer (score 11):

Column separation happens inside `container` elements.
Each time you have an element you want to do grid inside it, give it `class="container"` and in it u can use the normal `row` and `column` classes.

Also check Bootstrap's out of the box form styles.

Below are the bare bones, add on to it what u need (like text align etc)

```
<form class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="username" class="control-label">label</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="username" class="control-label">label</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The form already is inside container. Should I use containers inside the form? I do not get it.

Comment: Yes. give the form `container`. As u want the form to be a container of a grid, correct?

Comment: Form is within container. I do not understand how to divide it into two columns and if my solution is ok. What if adding form class container, the main question is how to divide into two columns as in the image. Shoudl I use rows? I am not in my example.

Comment: See my edit, for is within a container, but you want the form itself to ALSO be a container of a grid...

Comment: I understand your edit, but can you give me ideas why 'form-group' is used so widely? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Did not investigate thoroughly, But you will notice some of the out-of-box form related styles can group elements, I suspect it uses the form-group to identify such groups. I would also go a head and try use fieldset class=form-group instead of div, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem with bootstrap 4 and I found that whenever we want to divide inside our form into many columns we should use container and row class. because the bootstrap grid take its style from its parent (.container and .row)

see this example :

```
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <form  method="post">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6"> 
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-controllabel">Full Name</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" />
                            </div>
                         </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-controllabel">fatherName</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-controllabel">LastName</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" />
                            </div>
                     </div>
                            

         <div class="col-md-6">
                           
                <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-controllabel">salary</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" />
                            </div>
               </div>

              <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-controllabel">tax</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" />
                            </div>
               </div>
                 
                <button type="submit">save</button>   
                                    
        </div>

                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I'am sure it will work!